# what is the correct way to change column names order in asp.net grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

[image]

This is the error, how can I correct it. Anyone ..help 
I want to arrange `column` names in `Gridview`, I wrote the code as `C#`, but it didn't work.

```
namespace ip_web
{
    public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private void dgv1()
        {
            GridView1.Columns["no"].DisplayIndex = 0;
            GridView1.Columns["batch"].DisplayIndex = 1;
            GridView1.Columns["degree"].DisplayIndex = 2;
            GridView1.Columns["module"].DisplayIndex = 3;
            // dataGridView1.Columns["lecturer/instructor"].DisplayIndex = 4;
            GridView1.Columns["date"].DisplayIndex = 5;
            GridView1.Columns["time"].DisplayIndex = 6;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Service1Client com = new Service1Client();
            GridView1.DataSource = com.GetComTimeTable();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? The columns are index based: `GridView1.Columns[2]`, but even then there is no `DisplayIndex`. The only thing I can think of is that you are using auto generated columns and are trying to change their display order?

Comment: yes i want to change the display order

Comment: Why not use `BoundField` or `TemplateField`? Then you can control the column order. If the data is coming from a database you could even change the columns in the `select` query.

Comment: I could think of two approaches: 1) Use JQuery to manipulate the DOM and change the column order 2) Change the order of the underlying data. (assuming you are not autogenerating the columns). With this approach you could cache the data and just update your cache every time the user changes the column order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void dgv1()//show patient table
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns["id"].DisplayIndex = 0;
        dataGridView1.Columns["name"].DisplayIndex = 1;
        dataGridView1.Columns["gender"].DisplayIndex = 2;
        dataGridView1.Columns["age"].DisplayIndex = 3;
        dataGridView1.Columns["phone"].DisplayIndex = 4;

    }



 public void patientTableView() 
    {           //add to dataGridView

        Service1Client ptn = new Service1Client();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ptn.GetpatientTable();

    }


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//call the method when form loading

        patientTableView();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your tag `asp.net` and your example source, you have used `GridView`. Unfortunately there is not any property `DisplayIndex` in `GridView`. Please check [GridView Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx).

The property `DisplayIndex` exists in `DataGridView`, it's a `WinForms` control. Please check [DataGridView Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx). And `DataGridView` allow to get a `column` by using `name` and `index` both. Please check below image;

[image]